# Not able to hear sound from laptop speaker or Bluetooth speaker after Ubuntu 22.04.4 installation

Tags: drivers, sound, bluetooth, alsa, speakers

Not able to hear sound from laptop speaker or Bluetooth speaker after Ubuntu 22.04.4 installation but still can hear sound with earphones.

```
$ lsb_release -a | grep Description
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux ashish-Legion-Slim-7-16IRH8 6.5.0-25-generic #25~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Feb 20 16:09:15 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ sudo dmidecode -t 2 | grep "Manufacturer\|Product"
Manufacturer: LENOVO
Product Name: LNVNB161216
```

```
$ lspci -v | grep Audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 51ca (rev 01) (prog-if 80)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 22be (rev a1)
```

```
$ cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC287
Codec: Intel Raptorlake-P HDMI
Codec: Nvidia GPU a7 HDMI/DP
```

```
$ alsamixer
```

Here is the image of alsamixer.

[image: Here is the image of alsamixer]

```
$ sudo gedit /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-speaker.conf
```

[image: Here is the image after the above command]

Comment: I have the same issue with the same codec. I tried almost everything which was advised to do on this site but it still doesn't work.